# How to install UBIFS filesystem for SSD flash drive?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ubifs

I have SSD flash drive. So I want to make a new machine use UBIFS filesystem.

How can I do that? With Ubuntu desktop 17.0 dont have options for this filesystem.

And another question, with new filesystem, Could my machine run faster than ext2, FAT... filesystem? Because they are not designed to optimize for flash drive.

Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some result and found that. SSD called FTL devices, It transfer raw flash device to emulate block device with its controller. So My SSD can't use UBIFS like a filesystem. UBIFS just support for raw flash.

This link could make anything simple: https://digitalcerebrum.wordpress.com/random-tech-info/flash-memory/raw-flash-vs-ftl-devices/